# ResourcesUnavailable Error in C While Executing Progarm File?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUP4y.png)

Please check out this image and help me to resolve the error .

I try to compile and run my C program and expecting desire output but after creating executing program file  by the compiler , the .exe file disappeared and an error occurred.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not post pictures of text but instead show your code and error messages as formatted text directly in your question. You can use the `edit` button below your question to update accordingly.

Comment: Is there a file `Hello.exe` created when you compile your code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to program and run the executable in a Linux or wsl environment?

Unix uses forward slashes, try that.
./Hello

Also Unix doesn't create an exe extension file. It defaults to a.out unless you specify a name for it, in your case Hello.

Comment: The PowerShell window and the working directory `c:\ProgramsVS\C` don't really support the assumption that WSL might be involved.